# Can I separate searches into different divs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have set up a AJAX live search and I was wondering when I am pulling the information from the database can it be put into different result divs?

As I would like to style them separately. I would even like the to appear one at a time but I would like to sort out this first.

The way I have it set up now could work but it element.style is recking my vision :(

To say again when I search and when it returns the results could the go into different result divs?

**php**

```
<?php
/************************************************
    The Search PHP File
************************************************/


/************************************************
    MySQL Connect
************************************************/

// Credentials
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "zackreid_test2";
$dbuser = "zackreid_test";
$dbtable = "test2";
$dbpass = "test2";

//  Connection
global $tutorial_db;

$tutorial_db = new mysqli();
$tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$tutorial_db->set_charset("utf8");

//  Check Connection
if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/************************************************
    Search Functionality
************************************************/

// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
$html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
$html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';

// Get Search
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_REQUEST['query']);
$search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM search WHERE function LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

    // Do Search
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);

    // while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
    if ($result) {
        while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $result_array[] = $results;
        }
    }

    // Check If We Have Results
    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {

            // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
            $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['function']);
            $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['name']);
            $display_url = 'http://www.zackreid.com/'.urlencode($result['function']).'.html';

            // Insert Name
            $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

            // Insert Function
            $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

            // Insert URL
            $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);

            // Output
            echo($output);
        }
    }else{

        // Format No Results Output
        $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No Results Found.</b>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

        // Output
        echo($output);
    }
}


?>
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Periodic Table Search</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Load CSS -->
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Load Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:regular,bold" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Load jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load custom js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">

        <!-- Main Title -->
                <h1 class="title">Periodic Table Search</h1>
        <h5 class="title">A simple why to find the element you are looking for</h5>

        <!-- Main Input -->
        <div class="container-4">
        <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <!-- Show Results -->
        <h4 id="results-text">Showing results for: <b id="search-string">Array</b></h4>
        <ul id="results"></ul>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
/******************************************************************
This is the CSS Reset
******************************************************************/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    display: block;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(92,126,158,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(92,126,158,1) 0%, rgba(53,91,128,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(92,126,158,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(53,91,128,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(92,126,158,1) 0%, rgba(53,91,128,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(92,126,158,1) 0%, rgba(53,91,128,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(92,126,158,1) 0%, rgba(53,91,128,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(91, 122, 152) 0%, rgb(58, 86, 113) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5c7e9e', endColorstr='#355b80', GradientType=1 );
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
a {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/******************************************************************
Text Selection Styles
******************************************************************/

/* Safari, Chrome, iPhones, iPads */
::selection {
    background:#4096ee;
    color:#fff;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background:#4096ee;
    color:#fff;
}

::-webkit-selection {
    background:#4096ee;
    color:#fff;
}
/******************************************************************
General CSS
******************************************************************/
p {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: #616161;
    font-size: 10px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
h4 {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}
h5 {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
}
h6 {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 8px;
}
/******************************************************************
Main CSS
******************************************************************/
div#main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 360px;
    margin: 270px auto 20px auto;
}
.title {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0;  } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.container-4 {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn 1s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn 1s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
    animation:fadeIn 1s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

.container-4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s ;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s ;
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}


input#search {
    width: 350px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px #284561;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #ababab;
}



input#search:hover, input#search:focus {
    color: #3b3b3b;
    border: 1px solid #36a2d2;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
h4#results-text {
    display: none;
}
ul#results {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #77D2B3;
    width: 360px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) 0 1px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.15) 0 1px 3px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) 0 1px 3px;
}

ul#results:after {
        display: flex !important;
}

ul#results li {
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
}
ul#results li:hover {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
ul#results li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
ul#results li h3, ul#results li h4 {
    transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
ul#results li:hover h3, ul#results li:hover h4  {
    color: #3b3b3b;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Edit**

Forgot to mention this is a test version I am running, but here is it live;

http://dev.zackreid.com/test/download/Code/index.html

If you search for air it will return three results.

**Edit2**

Forgot to add the JavaScript;

```
/* JS File */

// Start Ready
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: narrow this down, buddy, you're pasting too much irrelevant code... by the way, where is your AJAX code? all I see is PHP and HTML in your question...

Comment: Guys, this is a legitimate request from someone who obviously doesn't master PHP and AJAX very well.... Give him a break, and help him.

Comment: @Webomatik you are very spot on with this statement lol :)

Comment: 1. As of jQuery 1.7, the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc) method is deprecated. 2. You can use the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function for each matched element

Comment: @aldanux Thanks I will look into this and try to see if I can get it to work :/

Comment: @aldanux When I add this in where I think its meant to go I get an error in my code :( I shall try to find another way thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I give you an "idea/example" how you can get your code working after I read your comment that you get error(s):

PHP File:

```
...

if (isset($result_array)) {

    foreach ($result_array as $result) {

        $isResult = true; // We set a variable for checking if we have a result or not

        $arrayFetch[] = [ 

           // Passing your result
           'output_1' => $result['foo_1'],
           'output_2' => $result['bar_1']
        ];
    }

} else {

    $isResult = false;

    $arrayFetch[] = [

        'output_3' => $result['foo_2'],
        'output_4' => $result['bar_2']
    ];
}

// We encoding to json
echo json_encode([

    'isResult' => $isResult,
    'result'   => $arrayFetch 
]);

...
```

Javascript (jQuery) File:

```
// Create a function to decode your result (I do it only for a cleaner code)
function getResult(data) {

    // Initialize your variable result
    var a = '',
        b = '';

    // Here we check if our $isResult are true or false
    if (true === data.isResult) {

        // Here came the .each() function in play
        $.each(data.result, function(i, obj) {                

            a = '<li>' + obj.output_1 + '</li>' +
                '<li>' + obj.output_2 + '</li>';                   
        });

    } else {

        b = '<li>' + obj.output_3 + '</li>' +
            '<li>' + obj.output_4 + '</li>';
    }

    // Return your result
    return a + b;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // I pick up your search function
    function search() {

        var query_value = $('input#search').val();

        // Ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json', // <== Notice the datatype:
                              // For transporting JSON-formatted data,
                              // which can include strings, arrays, and objects
            data: { query: query_value },
            beforeSend: function() { /* some loader */ }

        }).done(function(json) {

            // Putting result from function getResult() into your HTML 
            $('ul#results').html(getResult(json));

        }).fail(function() { /* some error handling */ });

        return false;
    }

    // Thats your original code, except that I change the .live() to .on() 
    $("input#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {

            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();

        }else{

            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });
});
```

Remember this is only an example!

You may read this for further info:

- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [.each() function](http://api.jquery.com/each/)